# Efficient way to take a Set of Lists, find their common elements, and sort the results using Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I've got an idea of how this could work, but it seems like there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

```
Set<List<SearchResult>> searchResults = new HashSet<>();
…
return searchResults.stream()
    .reduce((sr1, sr2) -> {
        sr1.retainAll(sr2);
        return sr1;
    })
    .get().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SearchResult::getDocno))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm streaming the Set, finding the intersection with `retainAll()` — so far, so good. But then `Optional.get()` needs to be streamed again so I can sort it. That doesn't seem right. Plus, my IDE suggests I need an `isPresent()` check, but I'm not sure how to fit that in.

Note: I can easily do this with loops, but I'm more interested in learning to work with streams.

Comment: what should be the behavior if there are not common elements in any of the lists? or to say the `reduce` returns an `Optional.empty`?

Comment: You are violiting the contract of reduce this way, you must return a *new* set all the time

Comment: Probably you need smth like `stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close IMO, it's just that `reduce` needs to return a new Object all the time:

```
searchResults
            .stream()
            .reduce((left, right) -> {
                List<SearchResult> list = new ArrayList<>(left);
                list.retainAll(right);
                return list;
            })
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(SearchResult::getDocno))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Correct. Only keep the elements that are present in all the lists.

Comment: yeah, even I thought the [`.orElse(Collections.emptyList())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139026/efficient-way-to-take-a-set-of-lists-find-their-common-elements-and-sort-the-r#comment91228030_52139026) was an unkwown in the question.

Comment: …so it’s obviously better to use `collect` here, to avoid copying the list over and over again.

Comment: @Holger only this morning I thought about updating this, if only I was not the baby sitter flr the day :| I will later, thank u!